# How to get rid of "npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, rename" on files that don't exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

This is my first actual question post. (Pls do not attack me if I do something wrong.)

I have node 5.6.0.

I have downloaded a JS web app for an assignment. However, I cannot actually work on the assignment because I can't get past the following error:

```
S:\PersonalCloud\jennylynneh\web development\code-academy\projects\project-2-beat-mix>npm install
npm WARN rollback Rolling back minimist@1.2.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat  'S:\PersonalCloud\jennylynneh\web development\code-academy\projects\project-2-beat-mix\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc'
npm WARN build-apis-beat-mix@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: rc@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: EEXIST: file already exists, rename 'S:\PersonalCloud\jennylynneh\web development\code-academy\projects\project-2-beat-mix\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.rc.DELETE\node_modules\minimist' -> 'S:\PersonalCloud\jennylynneh\web development\code-academy\projects\project-2-beat-mix\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules\minimist'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File exists: S:\PersonalCloud\jennylynneh\web development\code-academy\projects\project-2-beat-mix\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.rc.DELETE\node_modules\minimist

npm ERR! path S:\PersonalCloud\jennylynneh\web development\code-academy\projects\project-2-beat-mix\node_modules\.is-accessor-descriptor.DELETE\node_modules\kind-of
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno -4075
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, rename 'S:\PersonalCloud\jennylynneh\web development\code-academy\projects\project-2-beat-mix\node_modules\.is-accessor-descriptor.DELETE\node_modules\kind-of' -> 'S:\PersonalCloud\jennylynneh\web development\code-academy\projects\project-2-beat-mix\node_modules\is-accessor-descriptor\node_modules\kind-of'
npm ERR! File exists: S:\PersonalCloud\jennylynneh\web development\code-academy\projects\project-2-beat-mix\node_modules\.is-accessor-descriptor.DELETE\node_modules\kind-of
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.`
```

I have looked and I can't find any hidden files or folders related to these errors. Here is the list of what I've done in an attempt to resolve the issue:

1. Spoke to someone at Codecademy regarding the assignment zip files. They could not reproduce my issue.
2. Deleted the node_modules folder and ran `npm install` again.
3. Ran `npm install` a second time. This resulted in a different error regarding an invalid argument "read".
4. Deleted entire project folder, redownloaded, unzipped, and ran `npm install` again.
5. Uninstalled node, redownloaded node, and reinstalled node.
6. Repeated #4.
7. Ran `npm cache clean --force` and ran `npm install` again.

This part was supposed to take less than 2 min but now it's taken me over 3 hours. I just don't know what else to do. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any answers. :)

Jen

Comment: Have you tried using a different version of node and/or npm?

Comment: Yes, I tried the 6.1.0 version as well.

Answer (score -1):

It's due to npm. Try running this:

```
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/{username}/.npm"
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what this command is doing. Running `chown` as root in recursive mode can be dangerous, a warning would be appreciated. Also note than `{username}` can be replaced by `${USER}` for automated handling of the correct path.